# UFT API Test: How to read the User Variables and System Variables in custom code

Tags: c#, hp-uft, uft-api

I want to read the User Variables and System Variables in custom code of my UFT API test. How can I do the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, just insert this code in your custom code activity and it will take care of it.

Just replace the variable names that you want to capture.

```
string systemVar = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
CodeActivity4.Report("systemVar", systemVar);

string userVar = this.CodeActivity4.Input.myVar;
CodeActivity4.Report("userVar", userVar);

string testVar = this.Context.TestProfile.GetVariableValue("TestName");
CodeActivity4.Report("testVar", testVar);
```

Here here is the result:

[image]